# Change image source from url to drawable

Tags: android

I want to change the image source from url to image from drawable, 
In this way not work.

From:

```
public final static String[] imageUrls = new String[] {
        "https://ex/1.jpg",};
```

To:

```
public final static String[] imageUrls = new String[] {
    "@deawable/1.jp",};
```

Any kind of help or suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks !

I try to make a gallery,
This is what I did but still not working.

```
    public final static String[] imageUrls = new String[] {
    "android.resource://My.package.name/drawable/1.jpg",
    "android.resource://My.package.name/drawable/2.jpg",
    "android.resource://My.package.name/drawable/3.jpg",
    "android.resource://My.package.name/drawable/4.jpg",
};
```

Comment: What are you going to use the string for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are doing, but you could try this:

```
public final static String[] imageUrls = new String[] {"android.resource://your.package.name/drawable/1.jpg"};
```

Replace your.package.name with your package

Answer (score 0):

First you have a typo, it's `drawable` and not `deawable`. But whatever...

The thing is, to access android resources you have to go through the `R.java` file.
So you'll have to do the following :

```
public static final int[] imgDrawables = new int[] { R.drawable.1 };
```

This way, you'll access the images you put in the DRAWABLE folder on your project.

As you can see, it's now an INTEGER array, so you'll have to modify your code in order, either to use the resource id itself or use the following function to retrieve the drawable :

```
context.getResource().getDrawable(imgDrawables[0]);
```

Peace ! :)

**EDIT :**

As Simon André Forsberg said, `1` is an invalid resource identifier, you might want to reconsider your naming convention.

Comment: `R.drawable.1` is an illegal identifier, but whatever... :)

Comment: Ho yeah... Sorry, just rename the resource :p

Comment: Is it possible to give me more details... Thanks.

Comment: Come on man, you have everything you need... I cant write your code for you... Try and take a look at this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Comment: int[] should work fine. You can also use Integer[]. The ’Int’ was a typo.